# Jquery form serializeArray to string

Tags: jquery, tostring, serializearray

How to convert this array to string separated by commas with jquery?

```
var array = $('#form').serializeArray();
```

Thanks!

Comment: use map http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
    var array = $('#form').serializeArray();
    var arrayString = '';

    jQuery.each(array, function () {
        if (arrayString == '' || arrayString == null) {
            arrayString = this + "";
        }
        else {
            arrayString = arrayString + "," + this;
        }
    });
```

Or

```
var array = $('#form').serializeArray();
arr = jQuery.map(array , function(n, i){
  return (n.toUpperCase() + i);
});
var arrayString = array.join(",");
```

Comment: way to much invention ... `Array.join()` is your friend :)

Comment: I wish I knew that before i made the fuction :p nice to know :)

Answer (score 0):

> - by using  `$.map()` <sup>[doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)</sup>
> - demo https://codepen.io/luca-filosofi/pen/GRjKYYa

```
$(function () {
  var ATTRIBUTE_SEPARATOR = ":";
  var PROPERTY_SEPARATOR = ", ";

  // EXAMPLE 1
  var serialize_array = $("#form").serializeArray();

  console.log(serialize_array);

  var converted_string_1 = $.map(serialize_array, function (prop, i) {
    return prop.name + ATTRIBUTE_SEPARATOR + prop.value;
  }).join(PROPERTY_SEPARATOR);

  console.log(converted_string_1);
  // a:a, b:b, c:c, d[]:d1, d[]:d2

  // EXAMPLE 2
  var serialized_string = $("#form").serialize();
  var converted_string_2 = decodeURIComponent(
    serialized_string
      .replace(/\&/g, PROPERTY_SEPARATOR)
      .replace(/\=/g, ATTRIBUTE_SEPARATOR)
  );

  console.log(converted_string_2);
  // a:a, b:b, c:c, d[]:d1, d[]:d2

  // EXAMPLE 3
  var converted_string_3 = JSON.stringify(serialize_array);

  console.log(converted_string_3);
  // [{"name":"a","value":"a"},{"name":"b","value":"b"},{"name":"c","value":"c"},{"name":"d[]","value":"d1"},{"name":"d[]","value":"d2"}]
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have `a + a` on line 4. To make it work, I had to specify name and value: `return a.name + ': ' + a.value`.

Comment: @Jussi Hirvi: hi, tnx for pointing out the error, the 3d is too old to remember why i made that mistake, any way reading the OP question now, i see it's not clear what he want to achieve with that array, so i gived other possible versions... hope this help.